# In version 2.4 vector layers with labeling switch off caching

Tags: qgis, labeling, c++

I am developing a map display stand alone application using the C++ API.
With version 2.6 the caching mechanism is ignored for vector layers with labels.
The reason is to avoid conflicting labels.

The effect is that vector layers are rendered even if only the content of
other vector layers changed. As a consequence the map canvas display is flickering.

Does anybody have an idea how to let the labels of vector layers only be
calculated once. The cache image shall be used as long as the view extent is unchanged, even if there are conflicting labels.